# How to send a string array to the database and search one value at the time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, arrays

i started study html, php, mysql and jquery just a few weeks ago, but now i'm stuck with this problem: i need to create an array of strings from my user input field and then send it to my connect.php and do a mysql search for each of the words inside the array. I already tried with the .split(" ") method after `var value = $('#search').val();` and it didn't work. This is my code:

```
Index.php
    <html>
<headh>
    <title>Beta 1.0</title>
</headh>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
        $("#search_start").bind('submit',function(){ 
          var value = $('#search').val();
           $.post('connect.php',{value:value}, function(data){
             $("#search_results").html(data);
           });
            return false;
        });
      }); 
</script>

    <p id="p1">Hello World!</p>


<body align="center">
    <h1>Playbills</h1>
  <form id="search_start" action="" method="post"> 
     <input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search">
     <input type="submit" value="send" id="send">
    <div id="search_results">
      </div>
    </form>
    </body>


</html>
```

This is my connect.php:

```
<?php

define("HOST", "localhost");

// Database user
define("DBUSER", "root");

// Database password
define("PASS", "************");

// Database name
define("DB", "Beta 1.1");

// Database Error - User Message
define("DB_MSG_ERROR", 'Could not connect!<br />Please contact the site\'s administrator.');

############## Make the mysql connection ###########

$conn = mysql_connect(HOST, DBUSER, PASS) or die(DB_MSG_ERROR);

$db = mysql_select_db(DB) or die(DB_MSG_ERROR);

$query = mysql_query("
  SELECT * 
  FROM Film 
  WHERE name LIKE ".$_POST['value']."
");

echo '<table>';

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

  echo '
  <tr style="background-color:red;">
    <td style="font-size:18px;">'.$data["name"].'</td>
  </tr>';

 };    
    echo '</table>';          
        mysqli_close($link);

    ?>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Since you are just starting with PHP. PLEASE do not user `mysql_` library. It is deprecated and insecure. As long as you are learning, you should learn a modern library, such as `mysqli_` or `PDO`, that uses prepared statements and other modern features.

Comment: I understand you want the user to search more than one film each time he presses the send button, but if you split the input value using the blank space as separator, each word will be a different film, but most film names have few words. You would have to use a fixed separator (like comma, dot, hyphen, etc) or more than one input in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this would be helpful.

```
<?php
$listedNames = $_POST['search'];
$myArray = explode(' ', $listedNames);
$size = sizeof($myArray);
echo '<table>';
for($i=0; $i<($size-1); $i++)
{
 $query = "SELECT *FROM Film WHERE name LIKE ".$myArray[$i].";
   $result =  mysqli_query($db_connection_object , $query);


      while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

           echo '
                <tr style="background-color:red;">
                   <td style="font-size:18px;">'.$data["name"].'</td>
                </tr>';

                   }   

   }
  echo '</table>';  


?>
```